# Is there a way to display Customers info on this menu project?

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a project where I am able to manage customers, so I can view there info and be able to add or remove customers. Is there a way to show the customers info by pressing 2 on "DisplayMainMenu()"? And then it asks for your ID to show the customers info? I tried to do that on line 406, but I was not able to. I am guessing I have to get an array from the list? If so how could I improve my code?

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabMenu
{
public static class Program
{
    public static PreferredCustomer[] preferredCustomers;
    public static Customer customer;

    public static string firstName { get; set; }
    public static string lastName { get; set; }
    public static double flashlight { get; private set; }
    public static double iphone { get; private set; }
    public static double printer { get; private set; }
    public static double laptop { get; private set; }
    public static double playstation { get; private set; }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetPreferredCustomers(@"CustomerInfo.txt"); //
        DisplayMainMenu();
    }

    //the method below uses text file to add elements to the array
    static void GetPreferredCustomers (string path)
    {
        List<string> customers = new List<string>();
        int count = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                count++;
                customers.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        preferredCustomers = new PreferredCustomer[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string[] info = customers[i].Split(':');
            PreferredCustomer pc = new PreferredCustomer(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4], Int32.Parse(info[5]), Boolean.Parse(info[6]));
            preferredCustomers[i] = pc; //the array prefferedCustomers contains values
        }

    }
    public static void DisplayMainMenu()
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Menu!");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Quit");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Make An Order");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Manage Customers");

            switch (ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32(0, 2))
            {
                case 0: return;
                case 1: DisplayCustomersMenu(); break;
                case 2: GetData(); break;
            };

        } while (true);
    }

    private static void DisplayCustomersMenu()
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Make An Order");

            Console.WriteLine($"What is your first name?");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"What is your last name?");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            string strTarget = String.Format("Hello, {0} {1}.", firstName, lastName);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{0}",
                              Environment.NewLine, strTarget);

            Console.WriteLine("1) Select Customer");
            Console.WriteLine("0) Return to Manage Customers");

            switch (ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32(0, 3))
            {
                case 0: return;
                case 1:
                    {
                        string enteredID = "";

                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter the customer ID: ");
                            enteredID = Console.ReadLine();

                            //var id = ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32("Invalid customer ID", 0, Int32.MaxValue);

                            foreach (var id in preferredCustomers)
                            {
                                if (id.CustomerID == enteredID)
                                {
                                    DisplayCustomerMenu(customer);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You are not in the database");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            //return new Customer();

                        } while (true);

                    }
                };
        } while (true);
    }


    public static void DisplayCustomerMenu(Customer customer)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Manage Customers");

            Console.WriteLine($"Custumer name, ID and current order");


            Console.WriteLine("1) Add to Order");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Remove from Order");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Finalize Order");
            Console.WriteLine("0) Return to Manage Customers");

            switch (ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32(0, 3))
            {
                case 0: return;
                case 1: AddToOrder(customer); break;
                case 2: RemoveFromOrder(customer); break;
                case 3: FinalizeOrder(customer); break;
            };
        } while (true);
    }


    public static void AddToOrder(Customer id)
    {
            Console.Clear();

            int numberOfInputForFlashlight = 0;
            int numberOfInputForIphone = 0;
            int numberOfInputForPrinter = 0;
            int numberOfInputForLaptop = 0;
            int numberOfInputForPlaystation = 0;

            int myint = -1;

        while (myint != 0)
        {
            string group;

            Console.WriteLine("Add To Order");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Flashlight");
            Console.WriteLine("2) iPhone 7");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Printer");
            Console.WriteLine("4) Dell Laptop");
            Console.WriteLine("5) Playstation 4");
            Console.WriteLine("6) View Total");

            Console.WriteLine("[Press 0 to quit]");

            group = Console.ReadLine();
            myint = Int32.Parse(group);

            switch (myint)
            {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    double input1;
                    string inputString1;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many flashlights do you want?");
                    inputString1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString1);
                    flashlight += input1;
                    numberOfInputForFlashlight++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    double input2;
                    string inputString2;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many iPhone 7 do you want?");
                    inputString2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString2);
                    iphone += input2;
                    numberOfInputForIphone++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    double input3;
                    string inputString3;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Printers do you want?");
                    inputString3 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input3 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString3);
                    printer += input3;
                    numberOfInputForPrinter++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    double input4;
                    string inputString4;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Dell Laptops do you want?");
                    inputString4 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input4 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString4);
                    laptop += input4;
                    numberOfInputForLaptop++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    double input5;
                    string inputString5;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Playstion 4 do you want?");
                    inputString5 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input5 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString5);
                    playstation += input5;
                    numberOfInputForPlaystation++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("Flashlist quantity is {0}", flashlight.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("iPhone 7 quantity is {0}", iphone.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Printer quantity is {0}", printer.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Dell Laptop quantity is {0}", laptop.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Playstation 4 quantity is {0}", playstation.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Flashlight total is {0}", (flashlight * 15.00).ToString("C"));
                    Console.WriteLine("iPhone 7 total is {0}", (iphone * 700.00).ToString("C"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Printer total is {0}", (printer * 80.00).ToString("C"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Dell Laptop total is {0}", (laptop * 500.00).ToString("C"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Playstation 4 total is {0}", (playstation * 380.00).ToString("C"));
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input", myint);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void FinalizeOrder(Customer customer)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            return;
        } while (true);
    }

    static void RemoveFromOrder(Customer customer)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Remove From Order:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Flashlight total is {0}", (flashlight * 15.00).ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("2) iPhone 7 total is {0}", (iphone * 700.00).ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("3) Printer total is {0}", (printer * 80.00).ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("4) Dell Laptop total is {0}", (laptop * 500.00).ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("5) Playstation 4 total is {0}", (playstation * 380.00).ToString("C"));

            switch (ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32(0, 5))
            {
                case 0: break;
                case 1:
                    double input1;
                    string inputString1;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many flashlights do you want to remove?");
                    inputString1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString1);
                    flashlight -= input1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    double input2;
                    string inputString2;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many iPhone 7 do you remove?");
                    inputString2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString2);
                    iphone -= input2;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    double input3;
                    string inputString3;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Printers do you remove?");
                    inputString3 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input3 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString3);
                    printer -= input3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    double input4;
                    string inputString4;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Dell Laptops do you remove?");
                    inputString4 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input4 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString4);
                    laptop += input4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    double input5;
                    string inputString5;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Playstion 4 do you remove?");
                    inputString5 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input5 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString5);
                    playstation += input5;
                    break;

            };

        } while (true);
    }

    public static void GetData()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("CustomerInfo.txt"))
        {
            var index = 0;
            preferredCustomers = new PreferredCustomer[5];
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine().Split(':');
                var name = line[0];
                var address = line[1];
                var phone = line[2];
                var id = line[3];
                var email = line[4];
                var spentAmount = Convert.ToInt32(line[5]);
                var onEmailList = Convert.ToBoolean(line[6]);
                preferredCustomers[index] = new PreferredCustomer(name, address, phone, id, email, spentAmount,
                    onEmailList);
                index++;
            }
            GetID();
        }
    }


    public static void UpdateData()
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("CustomerInfo2.txt"))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var name = preferredCustomers[i].CustomerName;
                var address = preferredCustomers[i].Address;
                var phone = preferredCustomers[i].Phone;
                var id = preferredCustomers[i].CustomerID;
                var email = preferredCustomers[i].CustomerID;
                var updatedSpentAmount = preferredCustomers[i].CalcAmount();
                var onEmailList = preferredCustomers[i].OnEmailList;
                writer.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}:{6}",
                name, address, phone, id, email, updatedSpentAmount, onEmailList == true ? "true" : "false");
            }
        }
    }

    public static int GetID()
    {
        //id the user enters as input
        string enteredID = "";

        do
        {
            var customerIndex = 0;
            Console.Write("Please enter user ID: ");
            enteredID = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (var id in preferredCustomers)
            {
                if (id.CustomerID == enteredID)
                {
                    return customerIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    customerIndex++;
                }
            }

            Console.Write("ID does not exist. ");

        } while (true);
    }

    public static string UserChoice()
    {
        var userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        while (userChoice != "1" && userChoice != "2");
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Entry. Try Again.");
            DisplayMenu(); //Not working
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return userChoice;
    }

    public static void DisplayMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. Display Customer Info");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Update Customer Info");
        Console.Write("Please enter your choice: ");
    }
}
}
```

PreferredCustomers.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabMenu
{
public class PreferredCustomer : Customer
{
    public PreferredCustomer(string name, string address, string phone, string id,
        string email, int spentAmount, bool onEmailList)
        : base (name, address, phone, id, email, spentAmount, onEmailList)
    {
        DiscountLevel = SetDiscountLevel();
    }

    public readonly decimal DiscountLevel;

    public decimal SetDiscountLevel()
    {
        int range = SpentAmount / 500;
        switch (range)
        {
            case 0:
                return 0;

            case 1:
                return 0.05m;

            case 2:
                return 0.05m;

            case 3:
                return 0.08m;

            default:
                return 0.1m;


        }
    }

    public double GetDiscount()
    {
        return SpentAmount * (double)DiscountLevel;
    }

    public override double CalcAmount()
    {
        return base.CalcAmount() - GetDiscount();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            String.Format(
                "CustomerID: {0}\nCustomer Name: {1}\nCustomerAddress: {2}\n" +
                "Customer Phone: {3} \nCustomer Email: {4}" +
                "Customer Spending: {5:C2}\nCustomer On Email List: {6}",
                CustomerID, CustomerName, Address, Phone, CustomerEmail, SpentAmount, OnEmailList
                );
    }

}
}
```

Customer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabMenu
{
public class Customer : Person
{
    public Customer(string name, string address, string phone, string id, string email, int spentAmount,
        bool onEmailList)
        : base(name, address, phone)
    {
        CustomerID = id;
        CustomerEmail = email;
        SpentAmount = spentAmount;
        OnEmailList = onEmailList;
    }

    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public int SpentAmount { get; set; }
    public bool OnEmailList { get; set; }

    public virtual double CalcAmount()
    {
        return SpentAmount;
    }
}
}
```

CustomerInfo.txt

```
Alex Hernandez:123 10th st, Allen, TX 78714:972-555-0000:A0000001:email@gmail.com:2500:true
Albert Gomez:456 15th st, Austin, TX 78504:512-456-1000:A0000002:bobsmith@gmail.com:2500:true
Jose Martinez:2004 44th st, Washington, DC 20001:202-456-2222:A0000003:williamc@gmail.com:495:false
Joseph Olivas:123 16th st, Washington, DC 20002:202-555-6666:A0000004:garnerp@gmail.com:1200:true
Pablo Cortez:777 2th st, Houston, TX 77002:832-100-2000:A0000005:pcorzbin@yahoo.com:1750:false
```

Comment: Is all of this code relevant to the issue that you're experiencing?  Could you please edit you question to only include the code that is relevant to your problem.  That will make our lives a lot easier :)

Comment: We have already told you (previous question) to not post your whole code but only the [mcve] pertinent to your problem. All this info is just distracting

Comment: what do you mean show customer info? do you want just to print out all properties to console of Customer object?

Comment: Yes, I want it to print out all properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. 
I don't understand why do you need GetID() and method UserChoise() is never called.
Replace GetID() method with this one and add ShowCustromerInfo().

```
public static void GetID()
{
    //id the user enters as input
    string enteredID = "";

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter user ID: ");
        enteredID = Console.ReadLine();
        bool isFound = false;

        foreach (var customer in preferredCustomers)
        {
            if (customer.CustomerID == enteredID)
            {
                isFound = true;
                ShowCustromerInfo(custromer);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (!isFound)
            Console.Write("ID does not exist. ");

    } while (true);
}

public static void ShowCustromerInfo(PreferredCustomer custromer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}:{6}", 
    custromer.CustomerName, custromer.Address, custromer.Phone, custromer.CustomerID, custromer.CustomerID, custromer.CalcAmount(), custromer.OnEmailList == true ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
ShowCustomerInfo crashed but I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed ShowCustomerInfo to this code, and I was wondering if there was a method to add or remove customers as if they were arrays? For example, they are 5 customers and if want to remove 1 customer, could there be a way to do that?

```
public static void ShowCustomerInfo(PreferredCustomer customer)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("CustomerInfo.txt"))
        {
            var index = 0;
            preferredCustomers = new PreferredCustomer[5];
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine().Split(':');
                var name = line[0];
                var address = line[1];
                var phone = line[2];
                var id = line[3];
                var email = line[4];
                var spentAmount = Convert.ToInt32(line[5]);
                var onEmailList = Convert.ToBoolean(line[6]);
                preferredCustomers[index] = new PreferredCustomer(name, address, phone, id, email, spentAmount,
                    onEmailList);
                index++;

                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}:{6}",
                    name, address, phone, id, email, spentAmount,onEmailList);
            }
        }
    }
```